# comparing two 3-bit numbers with a 2-bit output

Tags: logic, circuit

I have two 3-bit numbers A2A1A0 and B2B1B0 and I have to compare them and generate a 2-bit output based on if A > B, A < B , and A = B.

The only circuit I can use to implement this is a multiplexer.

I've made a truth table; however, i'm not sure how to implement the 2-bit outputs. I was thinking of labeling A > B as 01, A < B as 10, and A = B as 11. But I can't find a way to put this in a multiplexer successfully, because each block of inputs will never have the same output.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: truth table]

Comment: You can avoid the last column A=B because if A>B=0 and A<B=0 implicitly means that A==B = 1

Comment: If you look closely at your truth table, you will notice that the column for `A==B` is equal to the `bitwise xor` of the columns `A>B` and `A<B`. You can drop the last column and simply return the 2 previous columns.

Comment: In summary, `A<B` will be `01`, `A>B` will be `10` and `A==B` will be `00` or `11`.